# error: conversion from ‘const char (*)[11]’ to non-scalar type ‘L::Entry’ requested g++ 4.4.5

Tags: c++, class, g++

alright so I am making dictionary class that takes an array of another homemade class: Entry... I am trying to make an array of Entries... I eventually managed to get rid of most of the errors... except one that states the error is in cstdio:

> error: conversion from ‘const char (*)[11]’ to non-scalar type ‘L::Entry’ requested

I can't figure out anything wrong but I have pinpointed that the array initialization is were the error starts up... heres the code for my main file that tests my Entry class:

```
#include "Entry.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
using namespace L;
int main(){
Entry entry("word", "definition");
cout << "entry's word is: " << entry.getWord() << endl;
cout << "entry's definition is: " << entry.getDefinition() << endl;

cout << "\n\n\n" << endl;

Entry entries[2] = {
    &Entry("Word", "Definition"),
    &Entry("Otherword", "OtherDefiniin")
}; 

cout << "entries's word is: " << entries[1].getWord() << endl;
cout << "entries's definition is: " << entries[1].getDefinition() << endl;
return 0;
}
```

and here is Entry.cpp:

```
#include "Entry.h"
#include <string.h>
namespace L
{
//constructors and destructors
Entry::Entry(const char *word, const char *def) : word(word), def(def){}
Entry::Entry(Entry &entryObj) : word(entryObj.word), def(entryObj.def){}
Entry::~Entry(){}
//setter methods
void Entry::setWord(char *newWord){Entry::word = newWord;}
void Entry::setDefinition(char *newDef){Entry::word = newDef;}
//getter methods
std::string Entry::getWord(){return Entry::word;}
std::string Entry::getDefinition(){return Entry::def;}
}
```

and finally Entry.h:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#ifndef ENTRY_H
#define ENTRY_H
namespace L
{
    class Entry
        {
        public:
            //constructors and destructors
            Entry(const char *word = "", const char *def = "");
            Entry(Entry &entryObj);
            virtual ~Entry();
            //setter methods
            void setWord(char *newWord);
            void setDefinition(char *newDef);
            //getter methods
            std::string getWord();
            std::string getDefinition();
        private:
            std::string word;
            std::string def;

        };


}
#endif
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you think this does?  `&("Word", "Definition")`

Comment: `Entry entries[2] = { &("Word", "Definition"), &("Otherword",  "OtherDefiniin") };` Whatever this is supposed to be, it ain't it.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal the & was put there because Entry() didn't work &Entry() didn't work... () didn't work so I thought that putting an ampersand there would make it a reference... the compiler didn't give me a direct error so I assumed it was okay.... sorry

Comment: Let this be a lesson to you. :) Hacking arbitrary symbols into your code to make the compiler shut up is **absolutely** _not_ a good way to develop software.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal     understood

Answer (score 5):

```
Entry entries[2] = {
    &("Word", "Definition"),
    &("Otherword", "OtherDefiniin")
};
```

What is `&(....)`?

I think you meant,

```
Entry entries[2] = {
    Entry("Word", "Definition"),
    Entry ("Otherword", "OtherDefiniin")
};
```

---

Also,

```
Entry::Entry(const char *word, const char *def){
    strcpy(Entry::word, word);
    strcpy(Entry::def, def);
}
```

First of all, why are you writing `Entry::word`?  Also, you've not allocated memory to `word` either.

I would suggest you to use `std::string`, instead of `char*` as:

```
//put them in the class definition
std::string word;
std::string def;

//constructor definition outside the class
Entry::Entry(const char *word, const char *def) : word(word), def(def) { }
```

And remove the other constructor which takes non-const `char*`. Its not needed!

Comment: okay... Im getting closer... after putting in your code there was only one error, when it inits the array with Entry("Word", "Definition") it tells me it could find a constructor with arguments: L::Entry... possible candidates are L::Entry&... when I go into the header and cpp file and get rid of the & sign and recompile... it gives me an error about that too

Comment: okay... I got even farther... I add the & to the front of Entry("Word", "Definition") but then it gives me and error saying..                                                     conversion from ‘L::Entry*’ to non-scalar type ‘L::Entry’ requested

Comment: @luckyl: Why did you go farther? What do you want to achieve by going *farther*?

Comment: @nawaz by going farther I mean going closer to no errors, you code didn't quite fix everything... it fixed everything but this one little error... however I do very much appreciate these code fixes

Comment: @luckyl: My code did fix the error. Its just your addition of `&` which is causing the error. If you add this, then its not the problem of MY code.

Comment: @nawaz alright I edited the code to my current status... also when I remove the ampersand from the &Entry(word, def) it gives me an error that it can't find a suitable constructor... also little things like the method: getWord wasn't returning a char* it was now returning a string... so I changed that... but none of it was a big deal

Comment: @luckyl: Add `const` to your copy constructor. Currently its `Entry::Entry(Entry &entryObj) ` which should be `Entry::Entry(const Entry &entryObj)`. Note the `const` in the parameter..... Also, DONT  write `Entry::word`. Simply write `word`.

Comment: @nawaz thank you... it didn't fix the error but it got rid of an annoying error and basicly compacked my code... thanks a lot... you helped me fix this and kept answering back... so thanks you quite a lot - luckyl

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... after messing with the code Nawaz gave me. I finally, for some reason enabled all warnings and found "address of temporary" I looked it up and then decided to try making the arrays equal to pre-initialized objects... ie

```
Entry *entry("Word","Definition");
Entry *entry2("Word2","Definition2");
Entry *entries[2];
entries[0] = &entry;
entries[1] = &entry2;
```

it finally worked without either a runtime error nor a compiler error

Comment: I have learned now to always enable -Wall and always watch the warnings